# Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the Web app resource paths:/WEB-INF/lib/WEB-INF/classes

Tags: java, rest

I am facing exception all the time I try to hit my REST APIs.

My code was working fine till yesterdays. Suddenly I started getting this exception.

I have added new jar files in the code. But haven't changed anything on my API code so far.

The exact exception I am getting is---

**Dec 11, 2019 11:45:18 PM com.sun.jersey.api.core.servlet.WebAppResourceConfig initINFO: Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the Web app resource paths:/WEB-INF/lib/WEB-INF/classes**

What should I do to fix this problem?

Comment: what is jersey version ?

Comment: Jar used is - jersey-bundle-1.14.jar

Comment: and the previous jar version?